# Greatest Common Divisor in a Diophantine Equation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, gcd-and-lcm

**Problem:**

[image]
[image]

***Question:***

How did the author derive  $$gcd(p-1,d)=1$$? how it is true?

**Reference:**

1. Page 33 of *An Introduction to Diophantine Equations* by Titu Andreescu, Dorin Andrica, Ion Cucurezeanu

Comment: What is $p$ here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$p$ is the least prime factor of $d$.  So $p-1$ contains no prime factor of $d$... (if it did $p$ wouldn't be the least such).  Since $p-1$ and $d$ have no prime factor in common,  they are coprime.